# Ruby: Searching an array based off of multiple keywords

Tags: ruby, class, web-scraping, class-method

Best way to search for multiple keywords through an array of instances (not like that matters, but that is my certain scenario)

```
all = [@sport = "string", @description = "string", @time = "string", 
@matchup = "string"]
```

The strings within these instances are scraped info from a TV schedule.  Currently, I am using "include?" and my app is working fine, but I feel like it can be refactored to be cleaner and more efficient.

Here is my current setup:

```
def self.select_by(sport)
    all.select {|object| object.sport.include?(sport) || 
    object.description.include?(sport) || object.matchup.include?(sport) || 
    object.time.include?(sport) }
end
```

I have 10 class methods to plug into the select_by method.  Example of one is below.

```
def self.football
    select_by("Football")
end
```

You get the picture :D

I set each self.insert_sport to a variable in my CLI and plug that variable into another method to display the proper breakdown based off of the instances in the array (sport, description, matchup, time).

I was just wondering is there a way to add more keywords without breaking my functionality too much.  As it stands, it works fairly nicely because the schedule is predictable and the keywords are consistent but since I am new to programming, I want to make sure to get in the habit of covering all my bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor the `select_by` method a bit:

```
ATTRIBUTES = %i[sport description matchup time]

def self.select_by(sport)
  all.select do |object|
    ATTRIBUTES.any? { |attr| object.public_send(attr).include?(sport) }
  end
end
```

Adding more attributes would be as simple as adding the attributes name to the constant.

Comment: This is awesome!  Thanks for the help on that portion.  As for the rest of the code, you think I may be pigeon holed into keeping the one-word keyword search?  Also, I have to explain this code, so now I am worried about explaining this method!  I will have to look up some of the details on it :D

Comment: Without knowing how you use the keyword methods and how your code looks like I actually do not see much benefit in these methods and would use `select_by(keyword)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I am going to take a deeper look at it!  Naturally, I would love to have someone like you help me with refactoring but since this is a project that will closely be examined, largely on how I explain it, code smell or not, I need to feel comfortable in what I have produced on my own.

Comment: @TylerP3358 probably would be a lot cleaner if `object` offered a method to return a flat  `Array` of `[sport, description, matchup, time]` maybe like `keywords` then it would be `all.select {|object| object.keywords.include?(sport) }`